# Cold wallet - got the 1 and L mixed up in private view key

Tags: cold-storage, viewkey

I just created a cold wallet on moneroaddress.org

I sent some Monero to the wallet.

I then tried to check the balance, which required my private view key.

It said view key was wrong. I am pretty sure I got the 1 and l in the key mixed up as the font is pretty much the exact same.

I have the 25 words, I have the spend key.

How can I recover the private view key?

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You can download and use the monero-wallet-cli to recover your wallet (and hence the keys) from your seed. See [here](https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/restore_account.html)

You can also use sites like [this](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) to generate the view key using seed or spend key. Although the site performs the operation locally (you can disconnect the internet when doing it) i still **recommend against it** for security reasons